# how can i create a splitted variable output for a bash program, like htop does to show variable outputs on different sections of the terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, htop

im trying to write a bash script and i want it to be able to divide the screen in 2 sections and show a message on one of them and the output of a command in the other without having to split the terminal window just like htop or nvtop. I looked it up everywhere and im not getting a place to start.

```
top segment: 
echo "now we are executing x command"

bottom segment:
sudo apt update -y
#above command's output
blablablablabla updating this and that 
updated 
your repositories work 
blablablablabla
```

image for reference :
[htop divisory lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qJ9M.png)

i looked everywhere on google and couldnt get a starting point, I also search for a way to leave a static header on the terminal with the command output refreshing underneat but still no luck finding something useful

Comment: Check https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/intro.html#WHATIS or some `tput` capabilities like `cuu1` to move the cursor

Comment: As a most basic feature, research how to have the `PS1` variable to always display at the top. It will involve using ansi escape sequences like `\032[m` .

Answer (score 0):

Your reference image is for [**bashtop**](https://github.com/aristocratos/bashtop)

That github project code would likely give you hints on how to proceed for what you want.